# archivos de descarga blob

Tags: javascript

comunidad buenas como están? he estado tratando de hacer que m archivo se descargue con el nombre y no con una serie de números aleatorios que arroja. como puedo corregir eso? aca esta el código
descargar(archivo) {
let dataURI = 'data:' + archivo.tipo + ';base64,' + archivo.codigo;
let byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]), ab, ia, linkElement, blob, url, clickEvent;

```
        ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
        ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

        for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
            ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
        }

        linkElement = document.createElement('a');

        blob = new Blob([ab],{ type: archivo.tipo });
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    //     console.log(url);
    //  let muestrame=url.split('/').pop().split('#')[0].split('?')[0];
    // //     // //esto permite acceder a los numeros con los que descarga el archivo
    //  console.log(muestrame);

    // let muestrame = url.replace(url, archivo.nombre);
    console.log(url.replace(url, 'prueba'));


         linkElement.setAttribute('href',  url);
        linkElement.setAttribute('download', archivo.nombre);

        clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
            'view': window,
            'bubbles': true,
            'cancelable': false
        });

        linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    }
```

Comment: Por favor coloca el código como texto, también puedes encontrar otras recomendaciones en [ask]. Recuerda que puedes hacerlo en cualquier momento haciendo clic en [edit]. Adicionalmente te invito a realizar el [tour] y ganar tu primera medalla.

Comment: ya quedo convertido en texto